# $C^1(K)$ is dense in $C^2(K)$ under sup norm if $K$ is cpt set in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $f$ is $C^1$ function on $[a,b]$ in $\mathbb{R^1}$, we can construct a sequence of polynomial $f_n$ which are uniformly converge to $f$ using stone-weierstrass theorem.
(i.e $\sup_{[a,b]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\rightarrow 0 $ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and $\sup_{[a,b]}|f_n'(x)-f'(x)|\rightarrow 0 $ as $n\rightarrow \infty$)

I wonder it hold in $\mathbb{R}^2$. In short, if $K$ is c'pt set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $f(x,y)$ is $C^1$ on $K$, Then there exist $C^2$ sequence $f_n$ which are uniformly converge $f$.

(i.e $\sup_{K}|f_n(x,y)-f(x,y)|\rightarrow 0 $ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and $\sup_{K}|\partial_xf_n(x,y)-\partial_xf(x,y)|\rightarrow 0,\sup_{K}|\partial_yf_n(x,y)-\partial_yf(x,y)|\rightarrow 0 $ as $n\rightarrow \infty$).

Comment: If $K$ has interior, $f\in C^{1}$  on some open set containing $K$ then this is true by Stone-Weiertsarss Theorem. In general $C^{1}$ on $K$ does not make sense.

Comment: I understand what you mean

Comment: You should modify the title: $C^2$ dense in $C^1.$

Comment: @geetha290krm There are several possible definitions (e.g.,due to Whitney) of $C^1(K)$ for general compact sets.

Comment: @Jochen When there are several possible definitions, OP should give the definition. Otherwise, the question does not make sense.